# How do I drag-and-drop files into a text editor in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

I installed Notepad++ and now want to drag-and-drop files into the editor. But I can't. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Drag them to the top bar where the file names are.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows8 and Notepad++ 5.9.6.2 :(

Comment: @andrecarlucci - Maybe some Windows 8 related bug? Try reporting it or search Google for a similar error.

Comment: I'm using NPP version 6.5.4 on Windows 7 and drag & dropping from local disk to NPP window worked fine, but drag & dropping from a  network location (mounted network share) onto NPP window didn't work at all. I was using just the Windows Explorer for file manager. The only way to open it was to right click on the file and choose Open With and select NPP (I have regular Notepad set as default txt editor), or open it through the Open dialog box inside NPP. It worked fine with MS Notepad though.

Comment: But this method worked for me, dropping it right where the tabs are. And now all of a sudden it decided to start accepting file drops anywhere on the program window (except the title bar). Strange... but it definitely works!

Answer (score 1):

Try to start Notepad++ with run as Admin once, then make sure “Settings -> Preferences -> Lock(no drag and drop)” has been unchecked

Restart Notepad++ again and try to drag and drop files to open. This is my trial and error the result is works for me.